# How do I go about estimating the interaction coefficient in logistic regression for an a priori power analysis?

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, statistical-power

I am running an a priori power analysis for a mixed effect logistic regression using simulation. In order to do this I need to have an estimate of the effect size I expect. I have a few control variables, and two binary variables of interest along with their interaction. I can come up with estimates for everything using previous literature *except* for the interaction. That is the novelty of the study.

How would I go about making a reasonable guess for that interaction coefficient? I know the pattern I expect (for there to be a larger effect of A in B1 vs B2). But I have no intuitive sense for how to come up with the interaction coefficient.

For the main effects I can at least de log the odds ratio to have some intuition. But I'm totally lost for interaction.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Say your binary predictors `A` and `B` are coded 0/1. If there is no interaction, then the coefficient for `A` is the change from baseline (`A=0`) log-odds when `A=1`, and similarly for the coefficient for `B`. Without an interaction, each of `A` and `B` affects log-odds additively, regardless of the value of the other.

With the interaction `A:B` added to the model, the coefficient for `A` is now the change from baseline log-odds when `A=1` *and* `B=0`. The coefficient for `B` is now the change from baseline log-odds when `B=1` *and* `A=0`. The coefficient for the `A:B` interaction is the *further difference* in log-odds when both have values of 1, versus what you would otherwise have predicted from their individual coefficients.

Your question implies that you expect this interaction coefficient--the *extra difference* in log-odds when *both* have values of 1--to be big enough to be of interest. So this isn't really that much different from any other power analysis to assist study design: how big an interaction coefficient do you want to be able to detect? What do you think that the variability in the interaction will be? Only you can answer that, based on your understanding of the subject matter.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! One wrinkle is that the predictors are going to be effects coded in my study, and I'm actually having a bit of trouble thinking through the interaction with effects coding. Would you mind walking me through how the answer changes with effects coding?

Comment: @Dave I don't work much with effect coding, so I'm afraid I'd be more likely to confuse than to clarify. As this is for a power analysis of a mixed-effects model, you're probably best off doing the power analysis by simulation anyway. Think this through with the dummy coding I suggested, set up your simulation accordingly, then see what you get when you analyze the simulated data with effect coding.